# Do tree based methods like random forest and gradient boosting produce unbiased estimates?

Tags: maximum-likelihood, random-forest, boosting, unbiased-estimator, estimators

Could anyone point me to literature that discuss properties of tree based estimators? For example, are they unbiased, consistent, maximum likelihood, efficient, etc?

Comment: Related: [Does LASSO suffer from the same problems stepwise regression does?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/411035/does-lasso-suffer-from-the-same-problems-stepwise-regression-does)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For random forests, Hemant Ishwaran (https://scholar.google.com/citations?hl=en&user=5PSPBOEAAAAJ) has published a few interesting papers with theoretical treatments of random forests, take this for example, on the consistency of Random Survival Forests: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0167715210000672

I would also recommend looking into these:

- Lucas Mentch, Giles Hooker (2016) *Quantifying Uncertainty in Random Forests via Confidence Intervals and Hypothesis Tests*; Journal of Machine Learning Research 17(26):1−41.
- G. Biau, L. Devroye, G. Lugosi (2008)
  *Consistency of random forests and other classifiers*
  Journal of Machine Learning Research, 9, pp. 2039-2057

Comment: thanks for sharing these articles. still looking for some info on unbiasedness and gradient boosting algorithms, if possible.